# How do I build up a LIN message and send it out in CAPL

Tags: bus, capl, canoe

I am a beginner in CAPL script. I am writing a script to send a 8 byte message with a frame id (PID). When i run the script in canoe, ECU does not give a response.Every thing in the setup and database is correct. There is a problem in script. Below is the script.

```
/*@!Encoding:1252*/
variables
{
   linmessage 0x11  Request;
   linmessage 0x25  Response;
   linmessage 0x01  Initiate_wake_up;

   byte WakeUpFrame = 0x3E;
   byte Request_Header = 0x11;
   byte Response_Header = 0x25;
}



void Util_SendHeader(byte frameID)
{
   Request.MsgChannel = 1;
   Request.ID = frameID;
   Request.RTR=1;  
   output(Request); 
}



void Wake_Up_Frame()
{
   Util_SendHeader (WakeUpFrame);
   Request.byte(0)=0x00;
   Request.byte(1)=0x00;
   Request.byte(2)=0x00;
   Request.byte(3)=0x00;
   Request.byte(4)=0x00;
   Request.byte(5)=0x00;
   Request.byte(6)=0x00;
   Request.byte(7)=0x00;
   Request.rtr=0;
   output(Request);  
}

on key 'q'
{
   Wake_Up_Frame();
   Request.byte(0) = 0x00;
   Request.byte(1) = 0x0A;
   Request.byte(2) = 0x00;
   Request.byte(3) = 0x00;
   Request.byte(4) = 0x00;
   Request.byte(5) = 0x00;
   Request.byte(6) = 0x00;
   Request.byte(7) = 0x00;
   Util_SendHeader (Request_Header);
   Request.rtr=0;
   output(Request);
   Util_SendHeader (Response_Header);
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

To send a LIN message, two `output()` calls are required: 1-st with `.rtr=0` and second with `.rtr=1`.

The first one schedules message data for transmission. The second one triggers the transmission.

If, instead of second `output()`, some external master sends the message header on the LIN bus, and the header ID matches the ID of scheduled message, the tool will transmit the message (acting as a slave).

To receive a message from slave, only the second `output()` is required. It will transmit the message header on LIN bus. Any slave that has a matching message ready (same ID) will transmit the message data.